# Problem while trying to set up bitcoinj

Tags: bitcoinj

I'm fairly new to programming and have only built some basic java applications, so bear with me. I'm trying to run the basic wallet application from the bitcoinj repository (using intellij and maven). I cloned the git repository, imported the filles as a Intellij project and added the dependecy to the pom file, but I still get these errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWHWh.png.

I tried everything I could imagine and can't fix it. If someone could help me I would appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jodyra, welcome to the Bitcoin Stack Exchange. If you haven't already, check out the [Tour](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [Help Center](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help). While your question relates to a Bitcoin project, it seems to be more of an IntelliJ/maven question. Hopefully someone will be able to help you (I am not), but you may want to start with IntelliJ tutorials.